# python3: lambda autoreduce works for maximum but not minimum function

Tags: python

If I do:

```
maх = lambda a, b: a if a > b else b
print(max(1,2,3))
```

it prints:

```
3
```

so the autoreduce is working.

But if I do:

```
min = lambda a, b: a if a < b else b
print(min(1,2,3))
```

it prints:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: I get exactly that same error for `max` so I suspect you may be calling the built-in `max()` which works with more than two arguments.

Comment: Let us see if anybody else reproduces my result. I am on Linux.

Comment: Was this done via jupyter?

Comment: No, just in a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you are actually *calling* the lambda in this case, instead you're calling the in-built `max` which is capable of handling more than two elements.

I base that on the following transcript (comments added):

```
pax:~> python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> maх = lambda a, b: a*2 if a > b else b*2 # cut'n'paste, add "*2" bits
>>> type(max)                                # entered by me
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> max(1,2,3)                               # entered by me
3

>>> max = lambda a: a+1                      # by me
>>> type(max)                                # by me
<class 'function'>
>>> max(1)
2
```

If you were calling the lambda, you would be getting `6` rather than `3` in that first section. In addition, with your definition above, `max` is *still* a built-in, not a function as per the second definition.

---

And the reason is that your lambda definition name is *not* the same as your call to it. If you take the first code block in the question and paste it into the [Unicode converter site](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) (replacing the newline with a space, you'll see it gives you (irrelevant stuff repaced with `...`):

```
ma%u0445%20%3D%20lambda%20a...print%28max%281%2C2%2C3%29%29
^^^^^^^^                   ...        ^^^
```

The `x` that you have used to define your lambda is [U+0445](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0445), "Cyrillic Small Letter Ha" (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kha_(Cyrillic)), *particularly* the bit "It looks the same as the Latin letter X").

If you use consistent naming, it would work (it may not necessarily be your fault, especially if you've copied that from the net somewhere- that's one reason why I got into the habit of code-point checking third-party code in the first place).

However, I'd probably *still* use a different name so as not to conflict with the in-built one (unless you have a pressing need to replace it).

Comment: I’m surprised his variable declaration isn’t overwriting the built in function

Comment: So your transcript seems to show that in the case, a 1-argument lambda will override a builtin but a 2-argument lambda won't. Which is kind of interesting. But even so, it doesn't really explain the difference from min. If I do `min = lambda a, b: a*2 if a > b else b*2` then `type(min)` tells me `<class 'function'>`, so here a 2-argument lambda is also capable of overriding a builtin.

Comment: @Keir, that *would* be strange but it turns out not to be the case. I've done some more analysis, it was difficult to work out because I was sometimes cut'n'pasting what you had and sometimes typing it in fresh, leading to some *very* weird and inconsistent results. It wasn't until I checked the Unicode code-point version of your question that I found the weird Cyrillic letter. The update explains it more fully.

Answer (score 2):

```py
maх = lambda a, b: a if a > b else b
print(max(1,2,3))
```

In the code above, the two names for the variable/function are not the same, here is what my IDE has to say about the definition, `maх`: *Identifier contains symbols from different languages: [LATIN, CYRILLIC]*.

The `max(1,2,3)` is calling the builtin-function `max()`, not the variable you defined.

This example might make things more obvious:

```py
t_1 = "maх"  # taken from the definition
t_2 = "max"  # taken from the function call

print(t_1 == t_2)
print([ord(curr) for curr in t_1], [ord(curr) for curr in t_2])
print(t_1.encode("unicode-escape"), t_2.encode("unicode-escape"))
```

Output:

```
False
[109, 97, 1093] [109, 97, 120]
b'ma\\u0445' b'max'
```